# Returning two objects from a function

Tags: r, list, function

I have two list objects that were created from two data sets. I created a function that removes some random components from each list. I would like the function to return these two list as an output.

For example I would like to get the new `list1` and `list2` objects when I run the `example_func`. I would like the output from the function to replace my old list objects and look something like the expected outputs.

Is this something that could be done in R?

```
value <- rep(c(1:5), 10)
id <- rep(c("A", "B"), 25)
df <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(id),
                 value = value)

list1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  group_split()

value <- rep(c(8:12), 10)
id <- rep(c("A", "B"), 25)
df <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(id),
                 value = value)

list2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  group_split()

example_func <- function(l1, l2){
  l1 <- l1[-c(1)]
  l2 <- l2[c(1)]
}

# Expected outcome
expected_list1 <- list1[-c(1)]
expected_list2 <- list2[-c(1)]
```

Comment: Your example `list` have only two elements

Comment: You can have it return a single list object with the mutated objects but you really shouldn't be aiming to directly modify global objects from within a function.

Comment: I've updated the example. Thanks @Axeman this is helpful but for the purpose for function  I was hoping to do it in just base r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zeallot` operator like so:

```
library(zeallot)

example_func <- function(l1, l2){
  l1 <- l1[-c(1)]
  l2 <- l2[c(1)]
  list(l1, l2)
}

c(expected_list1, expected_list2) %<-% example_func(list1, list2)
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about it